# What is the difference between re-render and re-load the page in React?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I want to understand if there's any other difference except when re-rendering, it only renders the updated data, while reloading the page will altogether send a new HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reloading is making another http request to the webhost's server. It returns html for your browser to load onto the page.

Rerendering is the act of changing, adding, or removing existing html on the page that has already been served to the browser. No need to interact with the website's server to make these changes. Keep in mind showing the actual content inside the new html element might make a http request.This is the entire point of JavaScript.

On stack overflow, you see the inbox icon on the top right? Click on it. Did the entire page reload for that single click to show your messages? It would if it was a refresh. But it didn't. Clicking on the inbox to show the new html element is a rerender.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of differences you expect? Re-render allows React to keep component's state which didn't re-rendered.